# How Google maps response when we enter in GMSCircle area

Tags: ios, google-maps, geofencing

Generally i want to make a GeoFence area and when i tapped in this area some action perform.

I searched from 2 days no help find on internet.

Is there any **GMS Delegate method** in Google maps to Enter and Exit in GeoFence area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native API from Google for iOS apps that can call a listener when the user enters or exits the geofence.

But you can always implement a location listener that checks for the users current location and notifies if the user enters or exits the geofence. Offcource this is going to be hard on battery and not good at performance, but unfortunately there is no native way of performing this operation.

Comment: thanks@AniV. what is another approach that can i use?